# I need to play a sound for a text based game in the cmd

Tags: java, function, audio

I need a function that I can call, that plays a sound. It needs to have a parameter where I can give it the name of the file I'm trying to play. I've tried searching on the internet, but it's all mostly based around the sun library. And that gives me a warning. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java media framework to play media. As for the method :) 
that you have to customize as per your need. 
Or if you just want beep sounds, you can use bell character or create beep using awt toolkit

```
//Bell character
System.out.println("\007");
//Toolkit
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```

Comment: Could you give me an example, with main and such. Im still a beginner at java. I also don't know what I should import for this.

Comment: For JMF refer 
[link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/samplecode-138571.html#JMStudio)

for beeps,
just try putting the code in main method.
*note: bell character sound will only be available in console.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Tutorials, for some reason, doesn't have a simple example of playing a sound in the fire-and-forget manner that you are asking about. But there are other tutorials online that do so.

The search term that will be of most help is "Clip" from the library javax.sound.sampled. This is a core library, so there is no need to import anything. The Clip class loads audio files in RAM, and allows you to play them back from RAM on demand. It is mostly used for short sounds. You should be able to find some code examples if you include "java clip" in a search.

Also in that library is SourceDataLine. This is often used for sounds that are too large to hold in memory. The class plays back data that you provide to its write() method. Thus it is common to pair the class with an AudioInputStream that was set up to read data from a file location. Again, there should be code examples if you search on the class name.

I made use of SourceDataLine to write a small audio library which can be found on GitHub, called [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue). The syntax is simpler than with Clip, assuming your source file is a wav file with 16-bit encoding, 44100 fps, stereo, low-endian (also known as "CD Quality"). To make use of it, there are six classes to load. You can just cut and paste. It is kind of a "super Clip" in that it allows extra capabilities like real time volume, panning and variable speed playback, as well as concurrent playback. There is a simple "fire-and-forget" example posted in the README.MD

The library is free to use. (BSD-type license.)